# Python PDFkit sending cookie issue

Tags: python, cookies, pdfkit

I am trying to use cookie with my pdf converter.
As i found [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) it looks like

```
--cookie <name> <value>         Set an additional cookie (repeatable),
                                  value should be url encoded.
```

So, I am trying to lauch it, but it always print me an error about

```
IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
**random key** specified in incorrect location
```

I wrote  `random key` because it is really one key from options dict, that work okay without `cookie`. And if i remove that key, he will write about any another.

```
options = {
    'cookie': 'pysid value',
    'page-size': 'A4',
    'margin-top': '0.59in',
    'margin-right': '1in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.59in',
    'margin-left': '1in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'footer-font-name': 'Times New Roman',
    'footer-font-size': 11,
    'header-font-name': 'Times New Roman',
    'header-font-size': 11,
    'header-right': "hehe",
    'footer-left': '[isodate]',
    'footer-center': '[page]/[topage]',
    'header-spacing': 8,
    'footer-spacing': 8,
}
```

P.S.
My wkhtmltopdf works nice with `wkhtmltopdf --cookie key value input output`